# Vagrant Windows Guest Timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, vagrant

I  had installed Vagrant on my VPS (DigitalOcean - centos 7) and I created Windows 10 Guest Box success in it.  But when i change my VPS (i using Google Cloud Platform), but when i run "vagrant up" to boot Box, this appears timeout although i have change timeout value. Same method config with D.O.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtUdo.jpg)https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPli6.jpg

Comment: This is not about programming, right?

Comment: right, but I think this relate to GCP, so i post this Question

Comment: I think the following [GitHub article](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-google) on this plugin in GCE will be helpful in this case.